# JSdoc how to tell that a function returns the same type as a parameter

Tags: jsdoc

in C# you would write

```
T RandomFrom< T >( List< T > list ) {
    return list[ ( int ) Math.Floor( new Random().Next() * list.Count ) ];
}
```

How should I do the same when documenting a JS function?
I tried:

```
/**
 * @type {*} T
 * @param {T[]} list
 * @returns {T} 
 */
function randomFrom ( list ) {
    return list[ Math.floor( Math.random() * list.length ) ];
}
```

But VS Code tells me `randomFrom(list: any[]): any` and I'd like it to be something like `randomFrom(list: <T>[]): <T>`. How do I achieve that? Putting the T inside `<>` makes it an arrow function.

Comment: Have you tried combining with a `@typedef` JSDoc block?

Comment: Look up [JSDoc @template](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#template)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
/**
 * @template T
 * @param {T} a
 * @returns {T}
 */
function (a){
  return a
}
```

Check out more: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#template